# Enviar um array de um select para uma URL usando ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho um problema que estou com muita dificuldade de resolver apesar de parecer fácil, e seria o seguinte:

Tenho este select com array:

```
<select id="cidade" onchange="fLoadBairro();"  class="search-box__combo" multiple name="cidade[]">
    <option value="0" id="cidade">Cidade</option>
    <optgroup label="Cidades">

        <?php 
        $sql = $MySQLi->query("SELECT id, cidade, uf FROM cidades ORDER BY cidade ASC");
        while( $linha_1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $sql ) )

        echo '<option value="'.$linha_1['id'].'">' .$linha_1['cidade'].'/'.$linha_1['uf'].'</option>';

        ?>

    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Notem que na tag `name:cidade[]`, até muitos sabem.

Agora este é o meu ajax:

```
////FUNCAO PRA CRIAR AJAX
function createXMLHTTP() {
    var ajax;
    try {
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            alert(ajax);
        } catch(ex) {
            try {
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch(exc) {
                 alert("Esse browser não tem recursos para uso do Ajax");
                 ajax = null;
            }
        }
        return ajax;
    }

    var arrSignatures = ["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP",
                            "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
    for (var i=0; i < arrSignatures.length; i++) {
        try {
            var oRequest = new ActiveXObject(arrSignatures[i]);
            return oRequest;
        } catch (oError) { 
        }
    }
    throw new Error("MSXML is not installed on your system.");
}

function ChamaAJAXDIV3(xDiv, xPagina, xVariaveis){
    var combo = createXMLHTTP();
    combo.open("post", xPagina, true);
    combo.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    combo.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (combo.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById(xDiv).innerHTML = unescape(combo.responseText.replace(/\+/g," "));
        }
    }
    combo.send(xVariaveis);
    alert(fVariavel);
}
```

E por último seria a função do Ajax que requisita a URL:

```
var $cidade = jQuery('form'),
data = $cidade.serialize();
function fLoadBairro(xDIV){
    with(document.busca){               
        ChamaAJAXDIV3("div_PesqBairros", "combo_cidades.php?id="+data);
    }
}       
alert(+data);
```

Veja que nesta função, tentei pegar o array vindo da tag `cidade[]`, e não estou conseguindo, mas se eu tirar os vetores da tag name cidade e colocar como cidade.value,  só irá pegar o primeiro valor da tag value selecionado da lista.

Eu preciso pegar esses valores destes values que forem selecionados e enviá-los como array, ou melhor lá na URL em vez de ir assim: `combo_cidades.php?id=1`, iria assim: `combo_cidades.php?id=1,2,3`, caso seja selecionado 3 checkboxes do meu select.

OBS eu uso a função MULT-SELECT que cria checkboxs dentro dos selects que todos sabem.

RESUMINDO : preciso que dentro do select quando abri-lo, e selecionar 3 checkbok com seus valores nos values, exemplo, value:com id 1, value:com id 2 , value:com id 3, pegar e passar pela URL para eu no PHP usar um explode e um `foreach` e separá-las, aí você poderão perguntar pra que tudo isso, é que quero aplicar isso numa COMBO BOX e preciso deste retorno pelo PHP para gerar os bairros de cada id selecionado na tag cidade , desde fico grato e desculpem pelo texto gigante, é para ficar mais esclarecido..

Comment: Você precisa converter para JSON para fazer isso ai. Provavelmente esse link pode te ajudar: https://jsfiddle.net/h5qqtn2g/

Comment: Olá amigo obrigado por responder ,mas não tem como fazer assim veja eu consegui chegar até a qui :  var valor = [];
valor.push('1','3');

for(var i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
 alert(valor[i]);
}

function fLoadBairro(xDIV){
with(document.busca){    
ChamaAJAXDIV3("div_PesqBairros", "combo_cidades.php?id="+valor);




   }
                                              Veja que dentro do push esta assim (1,2), teria como pegar dinamicamente vindo do php...

Comment: Mas porque você não usa o jQuery para fazer os ajax? É muito mais simples do que isso que você está fazendo agora... Você pode popular o select direto com o PHP, porém pegar os valores selecionados com o jQuery e usar o $.post() para enviar os dados via ajax.

Comment: Você poderia me dar um exemplo desta maneira, pois das outras que fiz , não obtive sucesso..

Comment: Você pode ler esses dois artigos da própria documentação do jQuery: 
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Comment: '<script language="javascript">
function Bairros(xDIV){
var select = document.forms[0].cidade;
var selectedList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
if (select.options[i].selected) {
selectedList.push(select.options[i].value);
}
}alert(Array.join(selectedList, ","));
ChamaAJAXDIV3("div_PesqBairros", "combo_cidades.php?id="+Array.join(selectedList, ","));
}</script>'

Comment: Usei este script acima e consegui resolver com ele, mas agora estou enfrentando outro problema , acho que este é mais fácil, pois eu consigo pegar este array com php e printá-lo e dividí-lo, mas eu preciso mostrar estes dados na tela porem quando eu busco os 2 ids marcados pelo checkbox o php só retorna o último dos 2 ids capturados, mesmo eu fazendo um foreach, tipo assim envio o id=1 e o id=2 e dentro desses ids tem uma coluna de bairros por que cada id representa uma cidade , aí neste ids 1 e 2 ele só mostra os bairros do id  2  e não do i , se eu selecionar ids 1.2.3.4,  só pega o último..

Comment: vou fazer o seguinte , como aqui não dá para colocar o código php meu para melhor entendimento, irei abri novo tópico para melhor compreendimento..

Comment: Coloque uma resposta na pergunta por favor...

Comment: Sobre a sua resposta eu li o tutorial e não tive muito exito para o que eu queria fazer mas agora o meu problema é que não consigo fazer um laço para impriimir todos os ids vindo do array.